# Prints in console but not when formatted to CSV

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have a program that groups data together and then gets the size of the groups. In the console it prints the group names and the counts perfectly. The only thing I do after that is use to_csv to put it in a csv. However in the csv it only shows the group counts not the group names

```
for f in xFiles:
    #Grabs just Reported Users
    info = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name="Reported Users")

    df = df.append(info,ignore_index=True)
    #Looking to sort based on color
df = df.groupby('Operator', as_index=False)['Operator'].size()
print(df)

#Writes to new file
df.to_csv('Weekly_Count_Per_OP.csv', index = False)
```

The console outputs as follows:

```
Operator
A                           45
B                           11
C                           52
D                           23
```

However, the CSV is as follows:

```
45
11
52
23
```

This error displays each time the script is run as well:
FutureWarning: The signature of `Series.to_csv` was aligned to that of `DataFrame.to_csv`, and argument 'header' will change its default value from False to True: please pass an explicit value to suppress this warning.
  df.to_csv('Weekly_Count_Per_OP.csv', index = False)

Comment: maybe for some reason in your code is considering "Operator" as index? have you tried without `index = False` ?

Comment: Sadly not that just simply puts a running tally on the side or not IE 0,1,2,3

Comment: First: this is not an error, it's a Warning :) . Second: have you tried to do what the Warning suggests? Does that resolve the Warning?

Comment: David, I don't entirely understand what that warning is suggesting. I won't lie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `df` is actually a `series` after groupby and then `sum` over a column. You need a dataframe, so that can store it as a `csv`.

Use below.

```
df.groupby('Operator', as_index=False)['Operator'].size().to_frame('count').reset_index()
```

To explain further, consider following example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Operator':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Operator
0   A
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   B
```

Now, let's do the operation.

```
s = df.groupby('Operator', as_index=False)['Operator'].size()
print(type(s))
```

Output:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

You will need a dataframe before you can make a csv file. Hence,

```
df = df.groupby('Operator', as_index=False)['Operator'].size().to_frame('count').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Operator    count
0   A             3
1   B             2
```

Then, use your code to export it to the csv file.

```
df.to_csv('Weekly_Count_Per_OP.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Simply changing the index = False to index = True in the to_csv line fixed the issue as well

Comment: It will still show the warning. :(. `to_csv` is applied on dataframe, not a series.

Comment: Correct but, when I do it this way it outputs completely different

Comment: Can you say what do you get?

Comment: It pulled everything from my sheets rather than the stripped down version I needed

Comment: I am not even reading the sheets with this code. Are you sure you are using my answer correctly?

Comment: I was not. I apologize. Like they say sometimes walking away helps

Comment: Sadly I don't have the Rep to bring it up any but I definitely will

Answer (score 0):

df.to_csv with the index=false will ignore the row names and not write them.  Try using index=True.

Comment: Everything else I used that added the counting on the side so I didn't even think to try that thank you

Comment: I can't get the warning to replicate but I have a feeling its due to not having the original dataframe you are grouping from and I don't feel like replicating it.  Check to see if the dataframe is truely a dataframe or a series after the groupby that might be it.

Comment: Uhh, It is a series. `.size()` gives a series. No need to replicate.

Comment: I believe it to be just a series which would then explain the warning

Comment: When I made a test really quickly to confirm the index issue in the csv file i explicitly made mine as a dataframe i didn't bother to fully replicate questioners code. As i understood the question to be more about the issue with the index not writing the csv file.